# Downloading an Excel File with php

Tags: php, laravel, download, phpexcel

I am trying to download an excel file to the client that I save on the server first (for backup purposes). The problem is I get a completely different file server side than I do client side. The server side is correct, the client side lists my sql queries and the time it takes. Note the xlsx is multiple sheets in one workbook and it needs to be that way.

```
public static function generate()
    {
        //Override the max execution time because our report takes longer than 30 seconds to run
        ini_set("max_execution_time", 300);

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objPHPExcel = ErsReport::generateDemographics($objPHPExcel);
        $objPHPExcel = ErsReport::generateWorkLocationTab($objPHPExcel);
        $objPHPExcel = ErsReport::generateDisabilityCategoryTab($objPHPExcel);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('ERS Reports\SpeedERS_'.date("Y_m_d").'.xlsx');
        //$objWriter->save('SpeedERS.xlsx');
    }

    public static function download()
    {
        header ('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
        header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ERS Reports\SpeedERS_'.date("Y_m_d").'.xlsx"'); 
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        readfile('ERS Reports\SpeedERS_'.date("Y_m_d").'.xlsx');
    }
```

I call generate then download. The generate shows the correct data. 
[image: Correct SpreadSheet]

When I call download it shows improper data and only one page.

**EDIT**

The function calling generate & download.

```
    function submitERSReport (formLocation) {
        {{ErsReport::generate();}}
        {{ErsReport::download();}}
    }
```

[image: Incorrect SpreadSheet]

Comment: Dont you see that it is not the file you download, your the output of your script?

Comment: Show us how you call `$obj->download()`.

Comment: I do, but I'm wondering how I can fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called it like this instead.

```
function submitERSReport () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/report/generateERS",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Request failed: getting ERS: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(msg){
                var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.style.display = "none";
                iframe.src = msg.filename;
                $('body').append(iframe);
        }
    });
}
```

With this controller.

```
public function action_generateERS()
{
    $filename = ErsReport::generate();
    return json_encode(array("filename"=>$filename));
}
```

And I made one change to the model.

```
    $objWriter->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ERS/SpeedERS_'.date("Y_m_d").'.xlsx');
    return('/ERS/SpeedERS_'.date("Y_m_d").'.xlsx');
```

It works now, but I'm still open to suggestions.